# Stop receiving from udpclient ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, udpclient, tpl-dataflow

I'm pulling in a list of ports to receive on from a database. I'm then taking those ports and creating list of UdpClients.

```
public static ConcurrentBag<UdpClient> Clients { get; set; }
```

I'm then selecting any channel that has data available and sending the UdpRecieveResult to a TPL Dataflow Buffer block.

```
 var readyChannels =
                (from channel in Clients
                 where (channel.Available > 0)
                 select channel);

 foreach (var channel in readyChannels)
                    {
                        // await on the result of the task                            
                        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReceiveAndRespond(channel));                            
                    }   


  async Task ReceiveAndRespond(UdpClient channel)
    {
        UdpReceiveResult? result = null;

        try
        {                
                result = await channel.ReceiveAsync();                
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            logger.Error("Error receiving from channel: " + exc.Message, exc);
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
                UdpData data = new UdpData() { Data = result.Value.Buffer, LocalPort = ((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port, LocalIP = ((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address, RemoteEndpoint = result.Value.RemoteEndPoint };
                await Flow.bufferBlock.SendAsync(data);
                logger.Info("Packet received from {0}", data.LocalPort);                                 
        }
    }
```

The exception:

```
Error receiving from channel: Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient'.
```

How can I stop receiving from the ReceiveAsync? So given the list of Udpclients listening, If I wanted to stop receiving from a a specific UdpClient how could this be achieved?

Comment: What is actually your question?

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: I need to be able to remove a UdpClient from the list. Currently when I do it throws a null exception. Its happening on the readyChannels linq statement.

{"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'."}

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: result = await channel.ReceiveAsync();

Comment: Please clear up your question. State explicitly which lines throw and add the exception message.

Comment: The exception clearly says that the clients have already been disposed. Where do you create the clients *and where do you dispose them*? If they go out of scope and get disposed before `await` returns, you'll get an exception as the one you posted